# Show UAC prompt before access is denied by IoCreateDeviceSecure function

Tags: c++, windows, security, driver

I am adding the access control for a driver (WinPcap's NDIS 6 filter driver) running on Windows 7 and 8. We want to let only administrators (users in Administrators group) to use the driver. So I used the new **IoCreateDeviceSecure** function instead of original **IoCreateDevice** call.

My code is as belows:

```
UNICODE_STRING sddl = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"D:P(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;BA)");
const GUID guidClassNPF = { 0x26e0d1e0L, 0x8189, 0x12e0, { 0x99, 0x14, 0x08, 0x00, 0x22, 0x30, 0x19, 0x04 } };
status = IoCreateDeviceSecure(adriverObjectP, sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION), &deviceName, FILE_DEVICE_TRANSPORT,
FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &sddl, (LPCGUID) &guidClassNPF, &devObjP);
```

My SDDL string is **"D:P(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;BA)"** which means **"allows the kernel, system, and administrator complete control over the device. No other users may access the device."** in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563667(v=vs.85).aspx.

It seems that only **build-in Administrator account** can directly access my device now. The **other members of Administrators group** will be denied because they don't have an escalated access token based on Windows's [User Account Control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772207%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). I know that when a user tries to make critical changes for the system, a **UAC prompt** will show up to the user to ask for permissions.

My question is, is there a way that **Windows shows such a prompt when executing my driver's IoCreateDeviceSecure call**, so **if the user agrees with the UAC prompt, the call can succeed**. The currently silent denial is not very friendly for a member in Administrators group to use rights. thanks!

---

More details:

My software is a combination of **some DLLs (wpcap.dll and packet.dll) and a driver (npcap.sys)**. **Other people develop the applications** (like Wireshark and Nmap) to use my DLLs and driver. The invoking path is: EXE -> wpcap.dll -> packet.dll -> npcap.sys. But getting app elevated also has issue. Because other people develop the apps. I'd like to **do the elevating thing in the DLL level**.

I have learnt that an application (EXE) can specify /MANIFESTUAC: highestAvailable in its manifest to enforce an Administrator elevation. I have tried to add  /MANIFESTUAC: highestAvailable option to a DLL too (in VS 2008, by modifying Properties -> Linker -> Manifest File -> UAC Execution Level to highestAvailable), but nothing happened. I doubt if it is meaningful to add such an option to a DLL. **Is there a way for DLL to enforce an Administrator elevation for the process that loads it?** So when an EXE (without /MANIFESTUAC: highestAvailable) loading my DLL (with /MANIFESTUAC: highestAvailable) tries to start, it will be required to be elevated by a UAC prompt?

Comment: UAC shouldn't be able to cause the IoCreateDeviceSecure call to fail, because that's happening in the security context of a device driver, not the security context of the user.  Do you mean that when a program calls CreateFile to open your device, *that* call fails?

Comment: Yeah, is there a way to let me do access control in the CreateFile function you said? to allow all members of Administrators group use the driver. It seems that I just need to change the ACL for my driver file (npcap.sys)?

Comment: My goal is to control the driver's access only to all members of Administrators group, whatever solution is ok. I have been stuck on the problem for a week! Need help and thanks!

Comment: No, the ACL for the file has nothing to do with it.

Comment: In *the program that calls CreateFile* (*not* the program that calls IoCreateDeviceSecure) you need to include a manifest that tells Windows to require elevation.  If you're using Visual Studio, you can do that with the /MANIFESTUAC linker option.

Comment: Hi. I tried to add the /MANIFESTUAC: highestAvailable to EXE, then the EXE shows the elevation prompt when started. The problem is my project is a combination of DLL and driver. **I only developed the DLL and driver for other people's EXEs to use.** So I can't force the EXEs to add the option. The invoke path is: EXE -> DLL -> Driver. I also tried to add /MANIFESTUAC: highestAvailable to my DLL. But nothing happened. And I didn't find any stuff useful for adding /MANIFESTUAC to a DLL. Is it meaningful to add /MANIFESTUAC to a DLL? Thx.

Comment: @hsluoyz: you cannot specify a UAC manifest for a DLL, it must be applied to the EXE. UAC applies to a process as a whole when it starts running, not to individual modules within the process. A process cannot be elevated after it starts running. Also, "highestAvailable" does not grant admin rights to standard users. If you require admin rights then use "requiresAdministrator" instead.

Comment: @hsluoyz: If you cannot require other people's EXEs to run elevated, you will have to either 1) move your DLL/driver logic into its own EXE that has its own UAC manifest requiring administrator access and then other people's code can communicate with your EXE using IPC mechanisms (named pipes, mailslots, sockets, etc), or 2) move your logic into its own COM object that other people's code can instantiate using the [COM Elevation Moniker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx).

Comment: It would be perfectly reasonable to do nothing other than document the fact that the executable must be run elevated.  It's the other developer's job to implement that.  However, if you want to go to the extra trouble of providing a COM object as per Remy's comment, some developers might make use of it, because it means they can more easily request elevation at the time they invoke your library rather than when the application starts.  Whether that is useful depends on what the application is for, so I'd recommend that you provide a plain DLL as well, since that's easier to use.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your guides! Eventually, we used the 1) way, we created an EXE run in Admin rights and communicate with it using Named Pipes. It seems to work find now!

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks! At last we created a new EXE run under Admin rights, COM is too complicated. It works more like a service instead of a DLL, and seems to be a new weak point compared to the driver. So I didn't use it. The EXE way works just fine now.